# how to handle errors from angular service inside controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I am new to angular, I am trying to access error message from service inside my controller

here's my service looks like

````
 admin.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(response){
              console.log(response)
           })

           .error(function(response){
              console.log(response)
           });
        }
     }]);```
````

and my upload function inside controller looks like below

```
admin.controller('uploadCtrl', function($scope, fileUpload){


 $scope.uploadFile = function(){
           var file = $scope.myFile;
           var uploadUrl = "/upload-url/";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl)
        };
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.post` returns a promise, and you can return that promise from the uploadFileToUrl function. Then if anyone needs to interact with the result, they can use the promise object.

Service:

```
admin.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
       var fd = new FormData();
       fd.append('file', file);

     //VVVVVV----------  added return statement
       return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
       })
    }])
```

Controller

```
admin.controller('uploadCtrl', function($scope, fileUpload){
    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
       var file = $scope.myFile;
       var uploadUrl = "/upload-url/";
       fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl)
         //VVVVVV------------ added .then and callbacks
           .then(
              function (result) {
                 console.log('success!');
              },
              function (error) {
                 console.log('error :(');
              }
           )
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, just realized it's ok to ask when stuck :D